# Graphing has several solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, analytic-geometry, quadratics

I have a simple graph question, but I can see a few potential answers.

The graph of $y = x^2 + px + q$ has a turning point at $(2,5)$. Find the values of $p$ and $q$.

Can someone explain why the correct answer is $p = -4 \text{ and } q = 9$?

The answer I got was $p = 0, q = 1$ and another answer I got was $p = -1, q = 3$.

Comment: Can you show your try?

Comment: with $p=0,q=1$ we have $y=x^2+1$ so that if $x=1$ we have $y=2$ and since $2 < 5$ then $(2,5)$ cannot be a turning point. With $p=-1,q=3$ we have $y=x^2-x+3$ and again with $x=1$ we see that $y=3 < 5$ so it is also not correct.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Are you saying that the (2,5) are x,y but are different to the x-squared at the beginning of the equation after equal sign? :-O

Comment: @securityauditor think about the shape of the parabola. The turning point is the minimum value of the function. This means at any other points the $y$ value must be larger than at the turning point. So this motivated me to check some values of $x$ near $2$ to see if they were smaller than $5$ as a way to check your answers. You can see for $y=x^2+1$ that if we set $x=1$ this gives $y=1^2+1=2 < 5$. Likewise for $y=x^2-x+3$ you get $y=1^2-1+3 = 3 < 5$. This means both of them fail to have a turning point at $(2,5)$.

Comment: I still do not understand why you are playing with the x value when the question clearly stated x=2 and y=5. Unless you are saying, the values of p and q must be such that any value of x like x=0, x=1, x=2, x=3 etc... must satisfy the equation by equalling 5?

Answer (score 4):

We are told that the turning point is at $(2,5)$.

We are given the leading coefficient is $1$,  the quadratic curve is $$(x-2)^2+5=x^2-4x+9$$

$p$ and $q$ are unique.

In general if the turning point is $(x_0, y_0)$ with the leading coefficient being $1$, the quadratic curve is

$$(x-x_0)^2+y_0=x^2+(-2x_0)x + (x_0^2+y_0)$$

The $p$ that you proposed doesn't satisfy the formula.

Answer (score 1):

$y=x^2+px+q$

$5=4+2p+q$

So $p$ and $q$ where $2p+q=1$ will have $(2,5)$ on the curve. It isn't a turning point though unless $2x+p=0 $ and $x=2 \implies p=-4$

Not a vertex: [image: (2,5) not a vertex]

Comment: In the 2 where did the 2 come from?! I know the x=2 from the (2,5).

Comment: $x^2+px+q=0.  $x^2+px+q= (x+p/2)^2 +q -p^2/4$ reaches a minimum when $x+p/2=0$ That's from completing the square. You can get the same result using calculus.  If $y=x^2+px+q$ then $y'=2x+p$. You get your turning points where $y'=0$ so $2x+p=0$.